# Cache-Control through Front-End?

Tags: javascript, html, http, http-headers

I'm having performance issues, and I noticed that my application is sending cache-control:no-cache in the HTTP headers. I've been researching methods on how to fix this, and ran across a few that mention putting a  tag like this could fix this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
```

Is this true? The results don't seem to be working -- many stylesheets, JS and JSON files aren't being cached at all  and I can't figure out a solution to help this.

Comment: Configure your server to send better caching headers.

Comment: @SLaks so there's nothing I can do on the front-end to aid this process? (in regard to cache-control and such?)

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664542/html5-meta-tag-cache-control-no-longer-valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the end, this is almost always better solved on the server-side. @RenanIvo did comment a good link on the depreciated HTML meta cache control, and im my experience the server is always the answer (or at least the best one).