# How to get around some caching or likewise?

Tags: html, css, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm experiencing some caching of scripts or caching of CSS that stops me from updating this is the update I'd like to do

[image]

It works locally and on localhost. But when I [deploy it to appengine](http://www.hipheap.com) it comes out like this like it's unstyled.

[image]

What can be done? The HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/theCss2.css?234" />
    <script src="/static/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/us1Config.js?1222343" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/theJava.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            addEvent('map_1');
            addEvent('map_2');
            addEvent('map_3');
            addEvent('map_4');
            addEvent('map_5');
            addEvent('map_6');
            addEvent('map_7');
            addEvent('map_8');
            addEvent('map_9');
            addEvent('map_10');
            addEvent('map_11');
            addEvent('map_12');
            addEvent('map_13');
            addEvent('map_14');
            addEvent('map_15');
            addEvent('map_16');
            addEvent('map_17');
            addEvent('map_18');
            addEvent('map_19');
            addEvent('map_20');
            addEvent('map_21');
            addEvent('map_22');
            addEvent('map_23');
            addEvent('map_24');
            addEvent('map_25');
            addEvent('map_26');
            addEvent('map_27');
            addEvent('map_28');
            addEvent('map_29');
            addEvent('map_30');
            addEvent('map_31');
            addEvent('map_32');
            addEvent('map_33');
            addEvent('map_34');
            addEvent('map_35');
            addEvent('map_36');
            addEvent('map_37');
            addEvent('map_38');
            addEvent('map_39');
            addEvent('map_40');
            addEvent('map_41');
            addEvent('map_42');
            addEvent('map_43');
            addEvent('map_44');
            addEvent('map_45');
            addEvent('map_46');
            addEvent('map_47');
            addEvent('map_48');
            addEvent('map_49');
            addEvent('map_50');
            addEvent('map_51');
        })
    </script>
    <style>
        .unselectable {
            -moz-user-select:none;
            -webkit-user-select:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>




<div onselectstart="return false;" class="unselectable" >
<div id="wrapper">

<h1 id="logo" class="sprite_index_in_in_en_logo spritetext">hipheap.com - The right choice for buying &amp; selling in usa</h1>


    <!-- map code -->
    <div id="map_base">

    <span class="tip" id="tip"></span>

<!-- the svg code starts here -->
<svg version="1.1" id="map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1080 720" xml:space="preserve">

  ...  
</svg>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these meta tags

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">  
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
```

Comment: this won't really work for HTML5 doctypes => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664542/html5-meta-tag-cache-control-no-longer-valid

Answer (score 1):

Name the file something different. This will force the browser to see it as a new file, re-download it, and apply the new styles.

Personally I do date-based version numbers, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile_20130405.min.css" />
```

Becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile_20130610.min.css" />
```

Perhaps that's overly simplistic of a change for your project, but a file name change is all it would take for the new styles to be applied right away.

Comment: If I rename files then the update comes through at first hit but then it loses the style on subsequents hits which is really strange. It's like the caching is not working.

Comment: ur saying that on future hits it no longer reads the new file? because that sounds ... wrong haha.

Comment: btw, i went to your link and the map shows up green just fine and dandy, i guess i'm not understanding what the specific issue is.

Comment: Changing file names is not ideal due to versioning of files. It should be a new version of the file and not a new file. And if I change files, the map loads ok at the first hit and then oddly enough it loses the styles. I emptied the cache of my local browser and tried on several different computers and now I'm getting it unstyled where it's deployed live while it's working well locally.  I don't under stand. <b>UPDATE</b>: It was the pagespeed service.

Answer (score -1):

Disabling the google pagespeed service was the solution.

Comment: try some real browser testing before you waste our time.

Comment: what do you mean? Should I expect the pagespeed service to break my style?

Comment: rule 1 of testing: test on all browsers to determine if it is a global issue, a browser-specific issue, or a machine-specific issue. i'm highly doubtful u would have seen this testing on IE or Opera. or on a different machine. you shouldn't expect anything, you should prepare for, and verify, everything.