# How to create a Random number or string in HTML without javascript or jquery

Tags: html

I want to generate a random number or string in HTML so that i add this to HTTP URL inside the HTML page to make it different each time page loads.

Answer (score 2):

That's impossible. HTML is a markup language, and cannot be used for defining logic.

Answer (score 1):

You should use server side scripting language for that.

HTML does not provide random number generation without using javascript OR jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to avoid cache problem insuring user has a different url each time he loads  the page, you can do something like :

```
<body onLoad="location.hash = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);">
```

Comment: yes i want to avoid cache problem but i cannot use javascript. I Think this will not work on the mobile phones those does not support javascript.

Comment: I would advise you to use meta tag then, but it doesn't seem a good idea. However, you have a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664542/html5-meta-tag-cache-control-no-longer-valid

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that works, because HTML is a static language.

Answer (score 0):

Something that uses php help? example :

```
<?php
$url ='https://linkexample/ws/'+ rand(1,100); + '.com';    
echo $url;
?>
```